# Simple array set doesn't show one of the keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have array with few keys inside but I can't see the content on page because of the error.

The array looks like this

```
{
    "224":
    {
        "title":"test",
        "description":"test description",
        "quantity":1,
        "price":1,
        "fileid":3
    }
    "225":
    {
        "title":"test1",
        "description":"test description1",
        "quantity":2,
        "price":2,
        "fileid":2
    }
}
```

When I foreach the the array on page like this

```
@foreach($orders as $download)
    @foreach ($download->getOrderData($download->order_details) as $itemId => $item)
         <pre>{{ $item }}</pre>
    @endforeach
@enforeach
```

The result is

> ErrorException: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
>   This I have in mu model

```
public function getOrderData($data) {
    return json_decode($data);
}
```

This is the query in controller

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', getCurrentUser()->user_id)->paginate(10);
```

If I try to get

```
<pre>{{ $item->price }}</pre>
```

this is working. But if I try to get

```
<pre>{{ $item->fileid }}</pre>
```

This gives me follow error

> ErrorException: Undefined property: stdClass::$fileid

update: DB structure

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `order_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(4) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1=paid;0=pending',
  `order_details` text,
  `user_address` text,
  `user_additional_info` text,
  `order_total_usd` double(20,8) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `orders` (`order_id`, `order_date`, `user_id`, `status`, `order_details`, `user_address`, `user_additional_info`, `order_total_usd`) VALUES
(57, '2017-07-17 10:51:44', 87, 0, '{"224":{"title":"test","description":"test description","quantity":1,"price":1,"fileid":3}}', 'address', '', 1.00000000),
(58, '2017-07-17 10:51:44', 87, 0, '{"224":{"title":"test1","description":"test description1","quantity":2,"price":2,"fileid":2}}', 'address', '', 1.00000000);

ALTER TABLE `orders`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`),
  ADD KEY `user_id` (`user_id`);

  ALTER TABLE `orders`
  MODIFY `order_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=58;
```

Comment: Why the php tag?

Comment: Sorry because I'm not sure where is the issue. Could be in PHP or in laravel model/blade. Either way php is involved here more than the blade template for example

Comment: Okay, now I understand

Comment: Are you sure there will always be a `fileid`?

Comment: @Jerodev, yes, default value is `0` not null

Comment: Where is this order data comming from?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm kind of novice in Laravel. And can't see in Controller function which saves order details in database anything related to $data.

Comment: Order_details are saved like this `$order->order_details = json_encode($cart, true);`

Comment: Where is `{{ $value }}` coming from??

Comment: Miss-typed on the question. Will edit it. Sorry.

Comment: What happens when you try this:

`<pre>{{  $item->fileid ? $item->fileid : 'N/A' }}</pre>`

Comment: This `ErrorException: Undefined property: stdClass::$fileid`. If I try this `<pre>{{ $item->title ? $item->title : 'N/A' }}</pre>` I've got both titles `test` and `test1`

Comment: Still not working huh? Can I see your migrations for your `Order` table?

Comment: I've used .sql file to import in database. I can show create table query in question. There is no FK's or something like this. Just a sec

Comment: The query which I used is added

Comment: Try dumping the content of `$download` and `$item` variables first.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getOrderData($data) {
    return json_decode($data);
}
```

This part returns an object (stdClass in PHP). If you instead want an array to be returned, you need to change it to this:

```
public function getOrderData($data) {
    return json_decode($data, true);
}
```

The second argument of `true` tells PHP to return an associative array instead of an object (stdClass).

Comment: This return `ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: You may have to change your references from `{{ $item->field }}` to `{{ $item['field'] }}`

Comment: But this doesn't explain why `{{ $item->fileid }}` isn't working. OP said that `{{ $item->price }}` is working.

Comment: Yes, as @Himal said others are working `{{ $item->price }}`, `{{ $item->description }}` etc

Comment: @user5996816 As i said before, try dumping the content of `$download` and `$item` variables first.

Comment: What you mean by dumping

Comment: @user5996816 Not familiar with laravel. but i think it has a [`dump`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-dd) function. something like, `{{ dump($download)  }}` `{{ dump($item)  }}`.

Comment: @Himal In Laravel, you can use `dd()` to Die & Dump (dump out and end the script): `{!! dd($item) !!}`

Comment: @Himal sorry for the late response when I run `dd($item)` I've got this: `object(stdClass)#454 (5) { ["title"]=> string(4) "test" ["description"]=> string(16) "test description" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> int(1) ["fileid"]=> int(3) }`. On `dd($download)` again this + all other columns and values in orders table

Comment: @user5996816 I don't think that `dd` is the way to go. becasue it seems to exit after the fist iteration. try `dump` function instead and you'll see if there are any null values.

Comment: @Himal `dump($item)` doesn't have `"fileid"` in it

Comment: @user5996816 Then that's your problem. make sure you have correct data on your database. additionally, you can check if a property exists using [`property_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php) function and ignore those accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is the problem. I don't know why I see it on order_detail array, on $download yet isn't in the array when is displayed on the page. I have no idea what can be the reason of that

Comment: But on `dump($download->getOrderData($download->order_details))` which is getting the order details I see it. And then I iterate over details in the foreach to get them in $item. Yet when iterate It doesn't exist any more